# How to migrate an old JCR file system repository to mongodb repository?

Tags: jcr, jackrabbit

How have a very old JCR (Jackrabbit) local file system repository, but the repository does not have a `repository.xml` (I do not know why). For this reason I cannot use the official command line [tool](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/migration.html), what can I do? Can I build the `repository.xml` manually? If yes, how?

Comment: Please note https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/3001761

Comment: because of the deadline I added the 'URGENT',

Comment: I found it. they put the `repository.xml` in project source codes!

Comment: @mhrsalehi did you find the solution?

Comment: no, but I found the `repository.xml` file!